# Software for finding polynomial equations for a suspected variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-software

The problem I have is the following. I have a subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ which I suspect to be an affine variety. I can generate as many as I would like random points on $S$, but their coordinates are as numpy floats approximations, rather than, say, exact values.

Is there a software that would take these points as inputs, and would give me, if they exist, the polynomial equations satisfied by these points, and thus, hopefully, by $S$? There are some complications due to the fact that the coordinates are approximations. So the software has to be able to handle some round-off errors. Also if someone knows of such a software, could they maybe also give me the name of the relevant command please?

Comment: Wow, an inverse problem.

Comment: Yes indeed. Inverse problems seem to be everywhere.

Comment: How do you describe the set $S$? Some geometric insight may be useful to find the equations.

Comment: The set $S$ arises as a set of singular values squared of a family of $n$ by $n$ matrices. More precisely to each configuration of $n$ distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, one associate such an $n$ by $n$ matrix, where each column is only defined up to a factor of $U(1)$. However, the singular values (squared) are well defined.

Comment: So often when people post these badly defined problems is because they have done some bad interpretation of what they need to solve their original problem. Just post the original problem that you are dealing with.

Comment: @user647486, it would take me a long time to explain the problem, as well as my approach. The problem is called the Atiyah-Sutcliffe conjectures on configurations of points.

Comment: The matrices are those of the coefficients of the polynomials coming from the $n$ points configurations?

Comment: Correct. The singular values are actually modified singular values so as to be $SO(3)$ invariant.